# Cleverbot API call returns 400 occasionally. Even with the same inputs

Tags: javascript, rest

I am using the cleverbot.io API to try to build a Spanish speaking bot by wrapping it's results in the Yandex machine translate API.

Cleverbot's API often returns a 400 error, but I can't track down why.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IxbK.png) is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

My code to make the request is based on the code examples provided at cleverbot.io:

```
function submitMessage() {
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   var x = $("#message").val(); // get user's message
   input.push(x); // push to array of inputs
   // append to HTML
   var x2 = '<div class="panel"><h5>Username @ date/time</h5><p>' + x + '</p></div>';
   console.log("input: " + x);
   $(".messages").append(x2); // add new response
   $(".mSent").html(input.length);
   
   bot.ask(x, function (err, response) { // collect ouput
         // CATCH 400 error and return message "I don't understand, please ask something else!"
         var y = response;
         console.log("output: " + y);
         output.push(y); // store output in output array
         var y2 = '<div class="panel callout"><h5>Juarez @ date/time</h5><p>' + y + '</p></div>';
         $(".messages").append(y2); // add new response
         $(".mRec").html(output.length);
        var end = new Date().getTime();
        var time = end - start;
        totalTime += time;
        avgTime = (totalTime / (input.length + output.length));
        $(".mTime").html(avgTime.toFixed(1));
    });
   $("#message").val(''); // reset input form
}
```

From my research on this site and others, I believe a 400 error describes a bad request usually because of a malformed URL. However, as you can see in the screenshot - some of the requests are identical and one will go through while the other wont.

If anyone could provide me a short snippet of code describing a better way of calling this API with input collected from the web form, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the text inside that error, as well as the header/response?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cleverbot.io API but they may use HTTP 400 for their custom error codes and have the custom code in the response body. Did you check that?

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda Here is the error response: http://i.imgur.com/773fPCU.png

Comment: Thanks, can you also post the header and response from the network tab? And @NarbehMirzaei is probably right in his assumption.

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda I'm going to look into how I can get the header and response from the network tab, I don't see it as an option. However, adding a timeout of a few seconds to the end of the function seems to have improved how often it works correctly. I am thinking the function might be terminating before it gets a response. 

Is this a plausible reason for a 400 error?